# MQTT - Getting the notification when message retention period is over

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have a requirement where I want to get some kind of notification while the message retention period is over and the message is about to be discarded from the MQTT topic.

So the actual requirement is, we have Bluetooth bands, which are send their presence through a centralized agent and an MQTT broker. Now we got a requirement where we need to upgrade the band firmware. For doing so, we will send a message to the topic with a message and a specific retention period. Infra will receive the message notification and look for the band. If the band is found then it's ok otherwise it will wait for new bands to be available. Once the retention period is over, in some cases we have to retry, so to implement the retry mechanism, I wanted to receive the notification from the MQTT broker if a message retention period is over.

Please help me if this is even possible into MQTT?

Comment: Why does a message alerting a firmware upgrade need to expire? It should persist so every device can see it and update. You can always replace it with the new version.

Answer (score 2):

The broker won't tell you when it drops messages, but since you know when you sent the message and what expiry time you set there is nothing to stop you implementing this yourself.